# Realtek HD Audio Mananger not detecting USB headset

Tags: windows, usb, audio, headset, realtek-hd-audio

I have a plantronics USB headset I purchased a couple of weeks ago. However when I open Realtek HD Audio Manager, the headset (and microphone) does not show up; my speakers do though but they're not USB speakers.

Is there something I'm missing here? Why isn't showing my headset properties (and settings) within realtek hd audio manager?

Answer (score 1):

If your USB headset isn't connected to the the onboard audio (e.g. 3.5mm jack), it's only natural the headset isn't managed by it or its driver.

USB headsets have their own controllers. They exist in a system just like extra USB sound cards.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel -> Device manager -> Sound, video and game controllers

- Uninstall headset (in my case it's "Logitech USB Headset H340")
- Uninstall Realtek High Definition Audio

Reconnect usb headset and Windows should detect it and reinstall

[image]